# Tkintertable change color of a cell/row

Tags: python, tkinter, colors

how do you change the BackgroundColor of a cell/ row with tkintertable? There is the command setcellBackground color, but it doesn't seem to work.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a bit of digging I found an answer, not the perfect solution, but doesn't matter:
You need to edit the color of the model itself with the command:

```
setColorAt()
```

The `setcellColor()` command still doesn't work.
Have fun and maybe someone can actually make sense of the command: documentation is on this site [tkintertable documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/tkintertable/tkintertable-module.html)

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the widget (Entry, Text, Listbox,...) you are placing on a certain row and column.

In a first part, you define the properties of the object, for example:

```
list = Listbox(root, borderwidth=0, background='white')
```

And then you tell tkinter where you want him to place the listbox:

```
list.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Is it clear ?

Please tell me which widget you want to put in your grid, it would be easier to help you!

Comment: Not the normal tkinter grid. The tkintertable table... Thats an own module, that has different functions

Comment: Have you read this @IcyTV ?

###Set preferences Preferences for the table can be set on the constructor method, for example:
`TableCanvas(frame, model=model,
               cellwidth=50, cellbackgr='#E3F6CE',
               thefont="Arial 10",rowheight=16,editable=False,
              rowselectedcolor='yellow',reverseorder=1)`

You can use `cellbackgr='#E3F6CE'` to choose the color of cells.

Does it solve it ?

Comment: Hi, no it doesn't really, because you set the color for all cells. See below for what worked